# RDP: Reset display scaling setting?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, scaling

I encountered a problem with a Windows 10 Enterprise system which is executing local GUI based programs executed on a logged-in local user account. This local user-profile is accessed from multiple computers with different monitors, some high-dpi, some not.

If I connect to that system using a PC with high-dpi monitor and screen scaling those settings are applied onto the user-session on the RDP connected machine as well.

Later if you connect to such a session using a PC with a non-high-dpi monitor (and thus scaling at 100%) the connected RDP session is not reset which ends up in all texts to be very small and next to unreadable.

**Is there a way to "reset" the display scaling settings of an active RDP connection (without log-off and re-logon the remote user)?**

The regular way to change scaling is blocked inside an RDP connection...

The RDP "server" is Windows 10 Enterprise 21H1, the clients 20H2.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://forums.windowscentral.com/microsoft-surface-book/406830-remote-desktop-scaling-how-fix.html) might help although the thread is from 2016.

Comment: If you're connecting to only a few servers, you could save the connection details in a `.rdp` file, including resolution. You then start the connection by executing the file.